# Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I am struggling with an error with a multi-modules project, the struture is simple, it looks like this :

```
 root 
   module a
   module b
   module c
   pom.xml
```

After using the maven command line : `clean sonar:sonar deploy`

I have this error :

> Failed to execute goal
> org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar
> (default-cli) on project X : Please provide compiled classes of your
> project with sonar.java.binaries property -> [Help 1]

EDIT : Here is the structure of my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <groupId>groupeId</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
    <version>version</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>${project.artifactId}-parent</name>
    <description>description</description>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0.603</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <modules>
        <module>module a</module>
        <module>module b</module>
        <module>module c</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Comment: add your pom.xml

Comment: Provide detailed structure and pom please.

Comment: Hello, I added my root's pom.xml, it is quite a simple one

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You're running your Maven steps in the wrong order:

- `clean` - delete all previous build output
- `sonar:sonar` - run analysis (which requires build output)
- `deploy` - build &etc...

Try this instead:

```
mvn clean deploy sonar:sonar
```

Now if you're about to object that you don't want to actually "deploy" the jar until/unless the changed code passes the Quality Gate, well... that requires a different workflow:

```
mvn clean package sonar:sonar
// check quality gate status
// if (qualityGateOk) { deploy }
```

The particulars of those last two steps will depend on your CI infrastructure. But for Jenkins, step #2 is [well documented](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzinginaJenkinspipeline)

Comment: Usually a `mvn clean package` is enough to do a `sonar:sonar` afterwards...and install is not really necessary..

Comment: Thx @khmarbaise. Updated

Comment: actually, only compile is just fine - in my case tests take really long, so it was the best.
and you don't need to add anything to pom.xml if you edit Maven settings

Answer (score 58):

I got the same error while invoking **Standalone SonarQube Analysis** as a Jenkins job pre-build step, which I fixed adding `sonar.java.binaries=**/target/classes` along with other SonarQube Analysis properties, as follows:

```
sonar.projectKey=TEST-PROJECT
sonar.projectName=TEST-PROJECT
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=src/main/java/
sonar.language=java
sonar.java.binaries=**/target/classes
```

Comment: It's worked for me... I just changing this property sonar.java.binaries=./target/classes

Comment: We can also assign full path sonar.java.binaries=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/$JOB_NAME/target/classes

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No files nor directories matching '**/target/classes'`

Answer (score 6):

I had a seme problem. I did below steps
Added Invoke top-level maven target from build steps (It should be the first build step)
added clean install.

and also added below properties to my   Analysis properties under Execute SonarQube scanner.

```
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=src/main/java
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.language=java
sonar.java.binaries=target/classes
```

Answer (score 6):

<sup>In my case works with:</sup>

```
mvn clean install sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=groupId:artifactId -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.login=loginHASH -Dsonar.sources=src/main/java/ -Dsonar.java.binaries=target/classes
```

rewrite:

```
mvn clean install sonar:sonar 
-Dsonar.projectKey=groupId:artifactId
-Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
-Dsonar.login=loginHASH
-Dsonar.sources=src/main/java/
-Dsonar.java.binaries=target/classes
```

Answer (score 3):

`mvn sonar:sonar` did not work in Jenkins although it worked from the command line.

`mvn compile sonar:sonar` worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but with BitBucket pipelines, so need to setup variables in `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`

```yaml
  - mvn compile
  - pipe: sonarsource/sonarcloud-scan:1.1.0
    variables:
      EXTRA_ARGS: -Dsonar.java.binaries=\"target/classes\"
```

Comment: This worked for me. Ffor a standard maven java project, surprised these settings are even required

Answer (score 2):

I have added the following properties to my **Analysis properties** under **Execute SonarQube scanner** section and my Java codes were scanned.

```
sonar.projectKey=investor2
sonar.sources=src/main/java/
sonar.language=java
sonar.java.binaries=.
```

[image: Jenkins SonarQube properties to scan java code]
[image: Sonarqube Output]

Answer (score 1):

For Java, the binaries are in the target folder. That's why you should use `mvn clean install sonar:sonar` to make sure your project is compiled and inside the target folder.

Sonar scans your binary classes.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 :- SonarQube File Location

```
C:\Program Files\sonar-scanner-4.7.0.2747-windows\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
```

Step 2 :- Open and Add this line

```
#----- Default source code encoding
#sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.java.binaries=**/src/main/java
```

Step Final :- Run the command on cmd

```
sonar-scanner.bat -D"sonar.projectKey=<YOUR PROJECT KEY>" -D"sonar.sources=." -D"sonar.host.url=<YOUR HOSTING URL>" -D"sonar.login=<YOUR LOGIN KEY>"
```

Example or Other configuration settings:-

```
#Configure here general information about the environment, such as SonarQube server connection details for example
#No information about specific project should appear here

#----- Default SonarQube server
sonar.host.url=https://codecheck.harriersys.com/

#----- Default source code encoding
#sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

#sonar.exclusions=**/*.java
#sonar.projectKey=com.example
#sonar.projectName=App Name
#sonar.projectVersion=1.0
#sonar.sources=D://App Name
#sonar.language=java
#sonar.java.binaries=D:/App Name/app/src/main/java

sonar.java.binaries=**/src/main/java
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that by passing sonar.java.binaries by maven tool.

> mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
>   -Dsonar.login=faeef1e48b8d00290a0f3cc00021720baf1ca4dd -Dsonar.java.binaries=D:\aiwb_s**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after a refactoring, a submodule was mistakenly changed to `<packaging>pom</packaging>` even though it contained Java sources and should be built as Jar.

Reverting that fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

This is a parent pom and has "pom" packaging. It doesn't contain compiled code.

You should put move the sonar.maven.plugin to the module poms that compile code.