# issue failed to execute a goal :sonarqube jenkins integration maven project

Tags: maven, jenkins, configuration, sonarqube

I’m trying to configure SonarQube plugin in Jenkins (Maven project)
I'm using:

```
 -Jenkins 2.89.4
 -java-8 version
 -Maven:3.5.4
 -SonarQube Scanner 3.2.0 (plugin installed in Jenkins)
 -Gitlab
```

For the Job configuration, I did the following steps:
Build Environment, I checked “Prepare SonarQube Scanner environment”
-For the build, I chose to invoke the top-level Maven target:

```
 Maven Version default
 Goals: $SONAR_MAVEN_GOAL -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL
 POM: path/pom.xlm
```

But, when I build my project, I have the following message:

> Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.1.1168:

[image: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.1.1168]

I would like to ask if i should add a plugin to maven if yes what is the version that i can use? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46976567/please-provide-compiled-classes-of-your-project-with-sonar-java-binaries?rq=1) SO question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46976567/please-provide-compiled-classes-of-your-project-with-sonar-java-binaries)